# Tell Git to ignore a file's whole contents moving down one line

Tags: git, indentation, gitignore

I grow weary of scrolling through massive change lists when someone simply added a new line to a file, and didn't actually change any characters/code.

**Is there any way to tell Git to ignore changes that only relate to additional empty lines, rather than characters?**

So with this file:

```
/* My file */
a line
another line
```

this change wouldn't be detected, despite everything moving down one line:

```
/* My file */

a line
another line
```

but this one would be

```
/* My file */
*more characters*
a line
another line
```

I know some coding languages are dependent on strict indenting/spacing to work, but some, like JavaScript, don't require spaces/tabs/returns to work at all.

Stop me if this goes against everything Git is designed to do, but while extremely thorough, it is also quite irritating when looking for the actual change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you want is the `core.whitespace` option. Look [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) for documentation.